# Increase size of tab bar item icons in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uitabbar

Is there a way to increase the size of tab bar item icons?
`.frame(width: 40, height: 40)` doesn't help.

```
Settings()
    .tabItem {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "archivebox")
        }
    }
    .tag(1)
```

Answer (score 19):

You can directly use font size like that (tested in Xcode 11.3).

*Please note that only works for symbol images (SF Symbols or . custom SVG symbols), it doesn't work for bitmap images.*

```
YourView()
   .tabItem { 
      Image(systemName: "heart").font(.system(size: 26)) 
      Text("Offers") 
   }
```

Comment: I've noticed on Xcode 12.0 beta 4 (12A8179i) running on the iOS 14 simulator, this no longer has an effect. The images are all a fixed size, which seems to correspond to the old `.font(.title)`.

Comment: @Jeremy have you found a solution for Xcode 12?

Comment: @ViktorSec No, unfortunately. :(

Comment: This only applies to Pre xcode 12, everything past that it seems im unable to adjust the TabItem label or image size. its always fixed no matter what i do

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `.font()` modifier to get a larger image:

```swift
YourView()
    .tabItem {
        Image(systemName: "…").font(.title)
    }
```

Sadly, the padding looks wrong with the image pushed right up to the top of the Tab Bar.

Answer (score 6):

You can create custom tabView to achieve custom height

attached screen shot showing the result of custom tabview which is inspired from this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/kishikawakatsumi/562028c46e7549aba658c88366417f6b)

```
struct TabView: View {
    var views: [TabBarItem]
    @State var selectedIndex: Int = 0

    init(_ views: [TabBarItem]) {
        self.views = views
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(views.indices) { i in
                self.views[i].view
                    .opacity(self.selectedIndex == i ? 1 : 0)
            }
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black.opacity(0.3), Color.black.opacity(0.4)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                            .frame(height: 70 + geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom)

                        HStack {
                            ForEach(self.views.indices) { i in
                                Button(action: {
                                    self.selectedIndex = i
                                }) {
                                    VStack {
                                        if self.selectedIndex == i {
                                            self.views[i].image
                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                 .padding(.top,10)
                                                .font(.title)
                                        } else {
                                            self.views[i].image
                                                .foregroundColor(Color.white.opacity(0.4))
                                                .padding(.top,10)
                                               .font(.title)
                                        }
                                        Text(self.views[i].title)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))
                                            .padding(.top,10)
                                            .opacity(0.5)
                                    }
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                .animation(.easeInOut)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TabBarItem {
    var view: AnyView
    var image: Image
    var title: String

    init<V: View>(view: V, image: Image, title: String) {
        self.view = AnyView(view)
        self.image = image
        self.title = title
    }
}


/// Main View
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    TabView([
      TabBarItem(view: Text("This is home screen"),
                 image: Image(systemName:"house.fill"),
                 title: "home"),
      TabBarItem(view: Text("2"),
                 image: Image(systemName:"heart.fill"),
                 title: "favorite"),

    ])
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! One small update related to iOS 15, `.animation(.easeInOut)` is deprecated already so use `withAnimation(.easeInOut) { self.selectedIndex = i }` closure-kind *explicit* animation inside Button's action closure to make the same eye-candy transition effect.

Comment: Agree with hamsternik -- solved my problem, and his animation suggestion is correct. The View tree can be simplified: both branches of the inner if are identical except for the foreground color, so you can eliminate the second branch and express the color as selectedIndex == i ? .white : .white.opacity(0.4).