# Resize a tab item from a TabView

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to resize one of the tab items in a `TabView`?

I tried `.font(.title)` but it doesn't do anything.

```
struct TabViewApp: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {

            Text("Tab 1")
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "star")
                Text("Tab 1")
            }
            
            Text("Tab 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar.circle.fill")
                       .font(.title)
                    Text("Tab 2")
                }
            
            Text("Tab 3")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "sun.max")
                    Text("Tab 3")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this [Increase size of tab bar item icons in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779126/increase-size-of-tab-bar-item-icons-in-swiftui)?

Comment: The custom TabView posted by `Jawad Ali` seems like a good solution and with a nice animation effect. I never thought I would need a custom TabView but it's good. Thank you for the link.